# Display image and title from json but message says cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

```
<section id="panel">
  <div class="container">
  </div> 
</section>
```

```
{
  "list": [{
      "image": "cat.jpg",
      "name": "meow"
    }, {
      "image": "dog.jpg",
      "name": "woof"
    }, {
      "image": "sheep.jpg",
      "name": "baaa"
    }, {
      "image": "bird.jpg",
      "name": "chirp"
    }
  ]
} 

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https-url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data.list, function (i, item) {
        $("#panel .container .col-sm-6").remove();

        var lastItems = data.list.slice(-2);
        var content = '<div class="col-sm-6">';

        content += '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + lastItems[i].image + '" alt="' + lastItems[i].name + '"/>';
        content += '<p>' + lastItems[i].name + '</p>';
        content += '</div></div>';

        $("#panel .container").append(content);
      });
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert('failed');
    }
  });
});
```

Json will be longer but regardless of the long number, I wanted to grab the last 2 details (images and name) which will be "sheep" and "bird" for example. `item.image` and `item.name` seem to work but with last 2 details, tried to use `lastItem[i].image` (same for name) and got the error message. Please help me with some guide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand in your code, you are getting the properties `cover` and `name` while the properties on your JSON are `image` and `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code

1. You are getting in your code the properties `cover` and `name` while in your JSON are `image` and `name`
2. In the each loop you will have an index bigger than the size of the list that you are looking for items (`lastItems`) In your example `i` variable can get the value 3, when the last index of `lastItems` is 1 (because the size is 2). So your success function should look like this:

   ```
    var lastItems = data.list.slice(-2);

   //You remove the item (this is not necesary to put it into the each loop cause it will return one item (due to you are looking for the element that has that id), if you have more than one then you have to loop through and do something like $(this).remove();
   $("#panel .container .col-sm-6").remove();

   //You fill the last 2 items
   $.each(lastItems, function(i, item) {

   var content = '<div class="col-sm-6">';
   content += '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + lastItems[i].cover + '" alt="' + lastItems[i].name + '"/>';
   content += '<p>' + lastItems[i].name + '</p>';
   content += '</div></div>';
   $("#panel .container").append(content); //This will cause an error casue the element with the id #panel will no longer exist (it will be erased with the last remove() call
   });
   ```

Comment: Brank - thanks for the explanation. my apologies for the above that I forgot to rename cover.